# word - merge mailing with specific fields if another specific field has a certain value

Tags: microsoft-word, merge, mail-merge

I want to do a merge mailing and I got the following issue

My word document is on the screenshot capture below

[image]

I want to put specific merge fields like `adr_A1` in `Adresse1`when my specific field,`siege_hr` has a value of `0` and I want to have `adr_A2` in `Adresse1` when my specific field,`siege_hr` has a value of `1`.

My excel spreadsheet look like this

[image]

I put an `if condition` and tried the 2 following formulas

1)  `IF{MERGEFIELD SIEGE_HR} = 0 {MERGEFIELD adr_A1} {MERGEFIELD adr_A2}`

2)  `IF{MERGEFIELD SIEGE_HR} = 0 "{MERGEFIELD adr_A1}" "{MERGEFIELD adr_A2}"`

For the latter, depending on the values of `siege_hr`, I have either adr_A1 or adr_A2 but not the values of adr_A1 or adr_A2. For the first, either `A1` or `mergefield` literally.

Any insights are welcomed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found my answer

When you do an `alt`+`F9`, don't manually insert the `{}`. Instead do an `ctrl`+`F9` then insert your mergefield `MERGEFIELD adr_A1` between the newly created `{}`.

It did the trick with me.

Cheers.